# How do I properly set bindings in JavaFX so that two rectangles retain their relative width and space between each other when the window is resized?

Tags: java, javafx, property-binding, hbox

I'm trying to create a bar chart as seen in exercise 14.12 in Introduction to Java Programming and Data Structures. I am so lost and incompetent when it comes to using JavaFX, that I currently I'm just trying to create two rectangles, that when you resize the window, their relative widths and distance from each other stay the same.

I tried this:

```
 HBox hBox = new HBox();
      
 Group group = new Group();
      
      
 Rectangle rectangle1 = new Rectangle();
 rectangle1.xProperty().bind(hBox.widthProperty().multiply((double)10/100));
 rectangle1.setY(100);
 rectangle1.widthProperty().bind(hBox.widthProperty().multiply((double)20/100));
 rectangle1.setHeight(400);
      
 Rectangle rectangle2 = new Rectangle();
 rectangle2.xProperty().bind(hBox.widthProperty().multiply((double)30/100));
 rectangle2.setY(100);
 rectangle2.widthProperty().bind(hBox.widthProperty().multiply((double)40/100));
 rectangle2.setHeight(400);

 group.getChildren().addAll(rectangle1, rectangle2);
            
 hBox.setPadding(new Insets(20,20,20,20));
 hBox.getChildren().add(group);
      
 Scene scene = new Scene(hBox);
      
 primaryStage.setScene(scene);
 primaryStage.setTitle("Bar Chart");
 primaryStage.show();
```

I would have expected that with the widthProperty of rectangle1 set to 20% of the HBox size, and the xProperty of rectangle2 set to 30% of the HBox size, that there would be a noticeable distance between the rectangles, but they are basically merged together.

Comment: @James_D Oh man. Whoops. I was having a brain fart moment and was treating the widthProperty as if it were just a second x value. I will look into overriding region as well. I am still very new to this and am not the best at finding the best way to do things yet. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Do you have to use `Rectangle`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rectangles are behaving more or less as expected. The `x` property of the first rectangle is set to 10% of the width of the `HBox` and its `width` is set to 20% of the width of the `HBox`, so it extends to 30% of the width of the `HBox`. The `x` property of the second rectangle is set to 30% of the width of the `HBox`, so it starts where the first rectangle ends.

Binding properties like this, however, is not the right way to lay things out in JavaFX. The `HBox` will try to resize if its child nodes resize, so that it can comfortably hold its children. If the size and position of the child nodes are bound to the size of the `HBox`, then they will resize if the `HBox` resizes. The library code is written to prevent any infinite recursion, but under some conditions it could be impossible to both satisfy the implicit dependency of the size of the container (the `HBox`) on the size of its children *and* the explicit dependency of the size of the children on the size of the container that the bindings create. You may notice at startup things don't quite look right (there is no gap to the right of the rectangles).

A better approach is to subclass `Region` and override the `layoutChildren()` method. You can then query the width and height of the region and set the size and position of the rectangles accordingly.

If you want to allow for padding in the region, use `snappedXXXInset()` (where `XXX` is `top`/`right`/`bottom`/`left`). For simple use cases you could omit this.

Here's a demo:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BarChartTest extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        HBox hbox = new HBox();

        Rectangle rectangle1 = new Rectangle();

        Rectangle rectangle2 = new Rectangle();
        rectangle2.setFill(Color.SKYBLUE);


        Region region = new Region() {

            // in reality these can be properties
            private final double prefBarWidth = 40;
            private final double prefBarHeight = 400;
            private final double verticalBarPadding = 100;
            {
                getChildren().addAll(rectangle1, rectangle2);
            }

            @Override
            protected void layoutChildren() {
                double x = snappedLeftInset();
                double w = getWidth() - x - snappedRightInset();
                rectangle1.setX(snapPositionX(x + w * 0.1));
                rectangle1.setWidth(snapPositionX(w * 0.2));
                rectangle2.setX(snapPositionX(x + w * 0.4));
                rectangle2.setWidth(snapPositionX(w * 0.2));

                double y = snappedTopInset();
                double h = getHeight() - y - snappedBottomInset();
                rectangle1.setY(snapPositionY(y + verticalBarPadding));
                rectangle1.setHeight(snapPositionY(h - 2 * verticalBarPadding));
                rectangle2.setY(snapPositionY(y + verticalBarPadding));
                rectangle2.setHeight(snapPositionY(h - 2 * verticalBarPadding));
            }

        };

        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(20,20,20,20));
        hbox.getChildren().add(region);
        // For demo, make region grow when window size increases:
        HBox.setHgrow(region, Priority.ALWAYS);

        Scene scene = new Scene(hbox, 440, 640);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Bar Chart");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Note I explicitly set the size of the scene here: that's because the region doesn't know how to calculate its preferred size (so by default it is zero). A slightly better solution would include that calculation:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BarChartTest extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        HBox hbox = new HBox();

        Rectangle rectangle1 = new Rectangle();

        Rectangle rectangle2 = new Rectangle();
        rectangle2.setFill(Color.SKYBLUE);


        Region region = new Region() {

            // in reality these can be properties
            private final double prefBarWidth = 40;
            private final double prefBarHeight = 400;
            private final double verticalBarPadding = 100;
            {
                getChildren().addAll(rectangle1, rectangle2);
            }

            @Override
            protected void layoutChildren() {
                double x = snappedLeftInset();
                double w = getWidth() - x - snappedRightInset();
                rectangle1.setX(snapPositionX(x + w * 0.1));
                rectangle1.setWidth(snapPositionX(w * 0.2));
                rectangle2.setX(snapPositionX(x + w * 0.4));
                rectangle2.setWidth(snapPositionX(w * 0.2));

                double y = snappedTopInset();
                double h = getHeight() - y - snappedBottomInset();
                rectangle1.setY(snapPositionY(y + verticalBarPadding));
                rectangle1.setHeight(snapPositionY(h - 2 * verticalBarPadding));
                rectangle2.setY(snapPositionY(y + verticalBarPadding));
                rectangle2.setHeight(snapPositionY(h - 2 * verticalBarPadding));
            }

            @Override
            public double computePrefHeight(double width) {
                return 2*verticalBarPadding + prefBarHeight + snappedTopInset() + snappedBottomInset();
            }

            @Override
            public double computePrefWidth(double height) {
                return prefBarWidth*5 + snappedLeftInset()+snappedRightInset();
            }

        };

        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(20,20,20,20));
        hbox.getChildren().add(region);
        // For demo, make region grow when window size increases:
        HBox.setHgrow(region, Priority.ALWAYS);

        Scene scene = new Scene(hbox);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Bar Chart");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I haven't had the time because of work to try this out yet, but had another question for you. Did you know how to solve my problem by overriding layoutChildren in Region because you have lots of experience? Would you recommend me trying to read most of the documentation for basic JavaFX, or will I learn this stuff naturally with more experience?

Comment: @user7179971 Both things are true :).  I am a strong believer in reading the Javadocs of everything you use. The more experience you gain the easier that becomes because you recognise the patterns behind the way things are designed. (And the more you read the docs, the faster you gain good experience.) That said, the documentation covering subclassing region and how to manage custom layouts is quite limited and I don’t think I would have understood it without extensive (>25 years) experience in other Java UI frameworks (so I know generally how these things are designed).